# Rest query to get all checked out file recursively

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest, csom

I want to get all files under document library which is checked out.

I tried this rest query in SharePoint hosted app

```
window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listid + "')/Files?$select=*,FileRef&$expand=File,CheckedOutByUser/Id,ListItemAllFields/ContentType,ListItemAllFields/File&$filter=CheckedOutByUser/Id eq " + _spPageContextInfo.userId;
```

I can get all root location checked out files by current user but how to get all checked out files under all folders also.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Grabbing info from: [Sharepoint REST api - Recursively fetch all folders in a document library -](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199925/sharepoint-rest-api-recursively-fetch-all-folders-in-a-document-library)

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, viewXml) 
{
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml
               }
    };

    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}

function getAllFolderItems(webUrl,listTitle)
{
    var viewXml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
    return getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewXml);
}
```

where the query is:

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
     <Query>
         <Where>
           <Geq>
              <FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser" LookupId="TRUE" />
              <Value Type="int">0</Value>
           </Geq>
         </Where>
     </Query>
</View>
```