# How to send a CAML Query with curl?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, odata, linux, curl

I've been using a CAML Query for getting all files in a document library in SharePoint 2013.

I used PnP with PowerShell for this purpose, but as I would like to get all files on Linux. I think it's feasable with curl with REST API but I cannot find the correct URL syntax. I would like to get at least all documents server relative urls and names (FileDirRef, FileRef, etc.).

I used this query taken from [sharepoint-rest-api-recursively-fetch-all-folders-in-a-document-library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199925/sharepoint-rest-api-recursively-fetch-all-folders-in-a-document-library), but I don't think it returns what I expect or I might not know how to parse it right.

```
$ curl -n "https://<site url>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('document library name')/items?$filter=FSObjType%20eq%201" -H "Accept: application/json;odata=verbose"
```

`-n` takes credentials from `.netrc` file.

I would like to send `<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type' /></IsNotNull></Where></Query></View>` (which returns the right answer with `Get-PnPListItem -List <library name> -Query "$camlQuery"`) with curl if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You use the [`SP.List.getItems`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245102(v=office.15)) method.

```
POST http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/getItems(query)
```

Here's some example code that demonstrates the use of this method. I don't use curl but I expect you should be able to adapt this sample for use with it.

```
var viewXml = {
    ViewXml: "<View>" +
        "<Query>" +
        "<Where><Eq>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Category' LookupId='True' />" +
        "<Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>" +
        "</Eq></Where>" +
        "</Query>" +
        "</View>"
}

var call = jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Products')/GetItems(query=@v1)?" +
        "@v1=" + JSON.stringify(viewXml),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    }
});
call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var message = jQuery("#message");
    message.text("Beverages");
    message.append("<br/>");
    jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) {
        message.append(value.Title);
        message.append("<br/>");
    });
});
call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var response = "";
    try {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
        response = parsed.error.message.value;
    } catch (e) {
        response = jqXHR.responseText;
    }
    alert("Call failed. Error: " + response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have seen such a query, but I would like the final URL if possible (that I can hopefully pass as an argument to curl). What is the `query` in `http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/getItems(query)`?  What is `@v1` used twice?

Comment: Could the command be `curl -X POST "https://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/GetItems('query=@v1')?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type' /></IsNotNull></Where></Query></View>"}', if only escaped correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used curl. I'm not sure how to format the HTTP request when using it.

Comment: Thanks. [how-can-i-use-caml-queries-with-the-rest-api](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/92cccd65-ba4c-4870-a858-7cd0e38a0482/how-can-i-use-caml-queries-with-the-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment) gives as an example `http://[site]/_api/Web/lists/getByTitle('[List]')/GetItems(<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef%20Name='Sector'%20/><Value%20Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>Value</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"}` with POST, but `X-RequestDigest` seems required.